# Non inverting Op amp resistors

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

So I have a voltage of 8.3mV going through the op amp and want it to amplify to 1.7V. So I know I need a gain of 200. Since I need two unknown resistors, how would I work that out using the non-Inv op amp equation? 
Thanks

Comment: One resistor needs to be 203.82 times bigger than the other resistor.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE - homework questions get a bit special treatment as we want to see what you have researched for yourself. What have you found and where are yuou stuck?

Comment: You need to choose a sensible value for one of your resistors, then rearrange the equation for the second resistor.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is homework without an attempt to solve.

Comment: @Andyaka In a practical setting, would a 1Ω and 203.82Ω resistor work? I'm not really sure why *the pros* use relatively high values tbh.

Comment: does it matter if the resistor is 200ohms or even 200k? Will it affect anything ?

Comment: Yes, 200 ohms will likely be too low and 200 kohms maybe too big.

Comment: What i mean was that , why would I choose the ratio for example, 2k,10ohm or 200k,1k or even 200ohm and a 1ohm resistors, as they all give a gain of 200?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *does it matter if the resistor is 200ohms or even 200k? Will it affect
>   anything ? – Q.T.π*

If the feedback resistor is 200 ohms then the grounding resistor needs to be 1 ohm and, the impact of this is that the op-amp's output has to drive a load of 201 ohms. So, if the op-amp is connected to the standard +/- 15 volt rails and is capable (or expected) to deliver an output range from -12 volts to +12 volts, at extremes, the output current will be very nearly 60 mA and far too much for most op-amps.

A typical limit might be 10 mA or even 5 mA.

So based on a 5 mA limit at 12 volts, the feedback resistor and grounding resistor should have a combined resistance of not less than 12/0.005 = 2400 ohms or \$R_F\$ = 2390 ohms and \$R_G\$ = 12 ohms (or nearest equivalent value).

But 5 mA may still be too much (in some applications) and you might go for 10 kohm and 499 ohm.

But why not go to 200 kohm and 1 kohm?

There are usually two answers to this: -

1. Input bias currents might start to produce a significant DC offset error
2. The value of 200 kohm for \$R_F\$ combined with the parasitic capacitance around the feedback node might mean that the amplifier runs out of steam at frequencies where performance is still expected.

For point 2 with \$R_F\$ = 200 kohms and a parasitic capacitance of 2 pF, the 3 dB point becomes about 400 kHz and this just may be too low. The only resort you have is to reduce \$R_F\$ and, taking it down to 20 kohm means that you get a bandwidth of 4 MHz for instance.

So, it's a balancing act of these things: -

1. Choice of op-amp
2. Battery life
3. DC error budget
4. AC high frequency performance

Comment: Thank you soo much for the explanation Andy! This makes a lot of sense, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how accurately you want the gain.

In a real non-inverting circuit, the current out the bottom of the smaller resistor, that current returning to VDD thru the power supplies, will **CAUSE AN ERROR** because of voltage drop in the Ground wiring/foil/plane.

Even in a Ground Plane, the current must spread out, and you should assume 0.002 ohms to 0.005 ohms of Spreading resistance. (this is based on 500 microOhms resistance per square of foil, any size square)

The real bummer is the Temperature Coefficient of this resistance:  +0.4% per degree C.